# Undefined index: avatar

Tags: javascript, php

I have this code to upload avatar.. It works fine but I get undefined index avatar, if I submit the form with empty avatar. The first code is php code then the Html code follows and the last code is the fileinput code. Thanks for you help pals.

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $adminID = $_SESSION['adminID'];

        if($_POST['avatar'] == ""){
            $error[] = "Please Select a Picture!";
            }

        $type = explode('.', $_FILES['avatar']['name']);
        $type = $type[count($type)-1];      
        $url = 'assets/images/users/'.$_SESSION['username'].'.'.$type;
        if(in_array($type, array('gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'JPG', 'GIF', 'JPEG', 'PNG'))) {
            if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'])) {           
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'], $url)) {

                    try {   //insert into database with a prepared statement
                            $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE admin SET avatar = '$url' WHERE adminID =  $adminID");
                            $stmt->execute(array(
                                $adminID
                            ));

                            echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL='.$location.'">';
                            exit;
                        } 
                    //else catch the exception and show the error.
                    catch(PDOException $e) {
                            $error[] = $e->getMessage();
                        }                       
                }       
            } 
        }   
    }
?>
```

Below is the HTML CODE for the file input, where user will use to select avatar

```
    <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
        <?php
            if(isset($error)){
                foreach($error as $error){
                    echo '<p class="btn btn-warning">'.$error.'</p>';

                }                                           
            }
        ?> 
            <input type="file" id="avatar" name="avatar" class="file" data-preview-file-type="any" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Save <span class="fa fa-floppy-o fa-right"></span></button>
```

Here is my fileinput plugin initialization code

```
<script>
    var btnCust = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" title="Add picture tags" ' + 
        'onclick="alert(\'Call your custom code here.\')">' +
        '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></i>' +
        '</button>'; 
    $("#avatar").fileinput({
        overwriteInitial: true,
        maxFileSize: 1500,
        showClose: false,
        showCaption: false,
        showBrowse: false,
        browseOnZoneClick: true,
        removeLabel: '',
        removeIcon: '<i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>',
        removeTitle: 'Cancel or Delete Selection',
        elErrorContainer: '#kv-avatar-errors-2',
        msgErrorClass: 'alert alert-block alert-danger',
        defaultPreviewContent: '<img src="" alt=""><h6 class="text-muted">Click to select</h6>',
        layoutTemplates: {main2: '{preview} ' +  btnCust + ' {remove} {browse}'},
        allowedFileExtensions: ["jpg", "png", "gif"]
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The code `if($_POST['avatar'] == "")` has the error. The `avatar` field belongs to the `$_FILES` array, not to the `$_POST` array.

Comment: Would need his form html to know for sure. Please Sam, add that. But its a pretty spot on stab.

Comment: @Randall sorry for the late reply I am having some internet issues. thanks, I have now added the whole code.

Answer (score 1):

You have referenced the `avatar` field once as a member of `$_POST` array, then as member of `$_FILES` array.

Simply change the `if` condition with the following to remove the error and also implement the logic you want to perform.

```
if($_FILES['avatar']['name'] == ""){
     $error[] = "Please Select a Picture!";
}
```

Comment: You can't say this if you don't know his HTML code, what makes you sure that there is no text input with the name avatar?

Comment: See the message which goes to `$error[]` array. It says, "Please select a Picture" which obviously means the user is trying to check for an uploaded picture - Not a text input with naem avatar

Comment: An educated guess is perfectly fine, when it turns out to be right. So this answer is well and fine acceptable.

Comment: @shahsani thanks for your help but I still get the undefined index avatar.. which is coming from the first line with avatar.

Comment: Have you put `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your FORM tag?

Comment: @shahsani yes I done that already... now the error only shows when I use edge browser but it works fine with chrome and firefox